# Windows 2k8 R2 DNS server - DNS request timed out

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have a problem with fresh installed AD/DNS server.

I have one domain controller that works as it should, without any issues.

Tried to install second DC at the second office. I've installed Active Directory role, executed dcpromo - everything went smoothly. But the DNS server on that new server doesn't work. When I tried to execute nslookup command, it says "DNS request timed out. timed out was 2 seconds."
And I don't have any ideas why. 
I've checked:
- DNS server service is running;
- it received info about zones from AD;
- DNS server is listening on all ip addresses (netstat confirms it);
- DNS has a reverse lookup zone with the ptr record for the new server;
- I don't see any DNS-related errors in the Event Viewer;
- firewall is completely off for a tests.

ipconfig from the server. 192.168.250.125 - LAN address, 10.0.9.103 - VPN 
tunnel, 192.168.0.11 - main DC

```
C:\Users\myuser>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : EX-DC2
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : MyDomain.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : MyDomain.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydomain.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-C6-AF-56
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No 
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.250.125(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.250.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.250.125
                                       192.168.0.11
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter OpenVPN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydomain.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-8A-C9-A1-FE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes 
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.9.103(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, January 24, 2018 3:17:18 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, January 24, 2019 3:17:17 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.9.254
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.250.125
                                       192.168.0.11
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.mydomain.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydomain.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\myuser>
```

nslookup:

```
C:\Users\myuser>nslookup ex-dc
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.250.125

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out

C:\Users\myuser>
```

I've tried to configure 192.168.0.11 (main DC) as the first DNS, 192.168.250.125 and 127.0.0.1 as the second and third. In that case:

```
C:\Users\myuser> nslookup
Default Server:  ex-dc.mydomain.com
Address:  192.168.0.11

> server 192.168.250.125
Default Server:  ex-dc2.mydomain.com
Address:  192.168.250.125

> ex-dc
Server:  ex-dc2.mydomain.com
Address:  192.168.250.125

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to ex-dc2.mydomain.com timed-out
>
```

Comment: A Domain Controller shouldn't use itself for Primary DNS (unless it's the only DC). It should use a partner DC server for Primary DNS. Configure the Primary DNS on this new DC to use the other DC, set the Secondary DNS to itself, and add 127.0.0.1 as Tertiary DNS. Reboot and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried but with no luck (added info to the question)

Comment: ask for 'ex-dc2.mydomain.com' instead of 'ex-dc2'.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked which interfaces it's listening on?  Open DNS->Right click on server and look at the interfaces tab.  With additional adapters (OpenVPN), you may need to set the option to "Only the following IP addresses" and choose 192.168.250.125.  If you change that, restart the DNS service and try nslookup again.